# Adding badges to file icons in Finder

Tags: objective-c, icons, overlay, finder

I'm working on a small project at home that would add a badge (aka icon overlay) to a specific file based on its state. Anyway, I've Googled the hell out of it and the only documentation I was able to find was on Apple's developers site ([Obtaining and Using Icons With Icon Services](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Icon_Service_nd_Utilities/03tasks/tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000916-3-TPXREF117)).

The documentation expects the developer to be familiar with Objective-C file APIs, which I'm not. So, I'm wondering if someone can please give me some code examples for adding badges to a file and directory. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

How about diving into the sources of [SCPlugin](http://scplugin.tigris.org/). I believe they are doing something that works. The code is here http://scplugin.tigris.org/svn/scplugin/trunk, login with "guest" and no password. I won't say it's easy...

[image]
<sub>(source: [tigris.org](http://scplugin.tigris.org/images/badging.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted to is for the Carbon (pre-MacOSX) API. Whilst it might work in the Carbon finder of 10.5, the Finder in 10.6 is pure Cocoa and as a result of which might not support the concept of badges in that regard.

You can add badges to an application in the dock with [NSDockTile](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html) but you won't have much luck in documents for applications on the whole. You'd either need to monitor the documents through some other mechanism and then use, say, a QuickLook plugin to generate a miniaturized view with whatever your state happens to be.

Failing that, you could write your own view for the documents (in which you could add such information) rather than using Finder.

Answer (score 2):

The Finder in 10.6 can be hack with a [SIMBL](http://code.google.com/p/simbl/wiki/Tutorial)
plugin , you just have to use the swizzling method to reimplement the drawWithFrame method in the Finder.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been around for awhile, but I know people are still looking so here's a completed solution for Finder icon badges and contextual menus in Lion and Mountain Lion using method swizzling.

[Liferay Nativity](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-nativity) provides a scripting bundle that will swizzle the relevant Finder methods and a Java client for setting the icons and context menus. It also includes equivalent projects for Windows and Linux.

The project is open source under LGPL, so feel free to contribute any bug fixes or improvements!

Comment: Does Liferay Nativity have any plans to support Python?

Comment: We're not currently developing a Python client, but all the communications happens via sockets, so porting the Java code shouldn't be terribly difficult. I'm actually in discussion w/ another developer who's writing some Python client code. We may end up adding his code to the repo.

Comment: Is there an example/explanation of how to install Liferay Nativity on an end-users machine as part of another app?  I wouldn't want them to have to install as "root".

Comment: Nativity currently uses ScriptingAdditions which will always require elevated privileges (either to copy the scripts to /Library/ScriptingAdditions or to invoke the scripts when in ~/Library/ScriptingAdditions). I think any other method (like SMJobBless) will still require admin privileges at least once.